# Typescript date validation format

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I am using Typescript for my app. I have two sets of data in the database, one is `date` and one is `time`. Both are expecting strings.

I made one `POST` request when the user chooses the date, and that time will be selected for the user. I made a helper function for when the user's choosing time will be over, in which case I show them an alert on front-end that shows

> "Your selected time expired!"

My logic works fine but I am trying to get rid of the Typescript error.

**Here is my [Typescript playground error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA3jAlhAKiAJgQwJ4BoYBmIATgLaawC+MAvDMQKYCOAroowBQBEWUDAtAUhcAlAG4AUBNCRYDAB4AHdg3QpEpBrRgdeDAFwxoxRGADm+KBoNGoJ8yNoA+eBJgwZ0GAG1sfvDCkpPjo6AC62noAdBCKADaIUNz8opLunrDo2mAMAO4wACIUDBzibjDoMQxQAGIscXEAmgyYxBz+2GXulRDVALLgUAAWHEEw-DAAjF0VVVBFfLroM4gEOshoWNi6Io5w5engXmAg+XSVUCDqmgDKdqZmpVHkUMAjAPQcADrocABMlH0P3+lBE+iiACp3iJvJMwml3B4jrBvNBWlB8AwwOFtFZNDF4olkqkpIj6NUWMQwDATvknHQ0cRYAAyZk004wAA8dCx6ARlHKjCglOpBEwcV6kkokmkyJgfHksB5ShUams3D+AAY-pN+JqAGz8Sb6rj4LiTTX6ACsVqNf30ms1ohgAH4YFwAPIAaS4MEMXAAoirGOguJJPCA4gwonEQI8FVBxEA):**

> Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.
>
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>
> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
>
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>
> Object is possibly 'null'.

**This is my code**

```
const { isToday, format } = require("date-fns");

const expiredTime = (date: string, time: string) => {
  const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split("-");
  const d = new Date();
  d.setFullYear(yyyy);
  d.setMonth(mm - 1);
  d.setDate(dd);
  if (isToday(d)) {
    const now = d.toTimeString().match(/(\d{2}:\d{2}):.*/)[1];
    const [start, end] = time.split("-");

    return now >= start && now <= end;
  }
  return false;
};

const text = expiredTime("2021-06-16", "10:55-12:00") ? "OK" : "Expired";
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Could state in your question what the actual error is?

Comment: You do not actually have any typescript here. You need to add the types (hence the name)

Comment: You can parse a string into an integer with the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should parse `yyyy`, `mm`, `dd` into number;
2. The result of regular expressions can be null;

Your code should be

```js
const { isToday, format } = require("date-fns");

const expiredTime = (date: string, time: string) => {
  const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split("-").map(parseInt);
  const d = new Date();
  d.setFullYear(yyyy);
  d.setMonth(mm - 1);
  d.setDate(dd);
  if (isToday(d)) {
    const matched = d.toTimeString().match(/(\d{2}:\d{2}):.*/);
    if (!matched){
      console.log("invalid date");
      return false;
    }
    const now = matched[1];
    const [start, end] = time.split("-");

    return now >= start && now <= end;
  }
  return false;
};

const text = expiredTime("2021-06-16", "10:55-12:00") ? "OK" : "Expired";
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript you posted was not complete.

- Note the optional chaining to handle the error of `Object is possibly 'null'`
- Cast to number using the unary `+` operator  - that saves a map to parseInt, the TS expects integers in the date constructor.
- Tell TS you are using a string array from the split

Lastly I changed the date creation. Separately setting the parts is not efficient. It was done while I still did not fully grasp your specs

```js
const { isToday, format } = require("date-fns");

const expiredTime = (date: string, time: string) => {
  const [yyyy, mm, dd]: Array<string> = date.split("-");
  const d: Date = new Date(+yyyy, +mm - 1, +dd);
  if (isToday(d)) {
    const now = d?.toTimeString()?.match(/(\d{2}:\d{2}):.*/)?.[1];
    if (now) {
      const [start, end] = time.split("-");
      return now >= start && now <= end;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
};

const text = expiredTime("2021-06-16", "10:55-12:00") ? "OK" : "Expired";
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it accept as an answer ? It does not give any time output